# asp.net event to set property before OnInit is executed

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, controls, page-lifecycle

I have a subclass of `Control`. This is a `ColorPicker`. I have the following property for it:

```
Private _Color As String
Public Property Color As String
    Get
        Return _Color
    End Get
    Set(value As String)
        _Color = value
    End Set
End Property
```

I have a `Page_Init` event, which contains the initialization of the control:

```
Protected Sub Page_Init(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Init
    '...
    If (maintType.FontColor IsNot Nothing) Then
        colorPicker.Color = maintType.FontColor
    End If
    '...
End Sub
```

And I have an OnInit event for the control:

```
Protected Overrides Sub OnInit(ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
    input = New HtmlInputHidden()
    input.Attributes.Add("class", "hidden-color-value")
    Dim picker = New HtmlGenericControl("div")
    picker.Attributes.Add("class", "picker-color-value")
    picker.Style.Add("width", "220px")
    picker.Style.Add("height", "220px")
    Dim selectedColor = New HtmlGenericControl("div")
    selectedColor.Style.Add("width", "100px")
    selectedColor.Style.Add("height", "100px")
    selectedColor.Style.Add("margin-top", "50px")
    selectedColor.Style.Add("background-color", input.Value)
    selectedColor.Attributes.Add("class", "selected-color")
    input.Value = If(Color Is Nothing, "#000000", Color)
    Me.Controls.Add(input)
    Me.Controls.Add(picker)
    Me.Controls.Add(selectedColor)
    MyBase.OnInit(e)
End Sub
```

The problem is that the `Color` property is used for the initialization of `input.Value` before the `Property` is initialized. I have tried to put things into `OnPreRender`, but that prevented the `Control` from rendering. So, my question is about the place where input should be added to the controls, the place where `input.Value` should be initialized in the Control code and the place where the Color property should be set.

Comment: I used to pass Input parameters to Controls by adding those values in ASPX page; `<cc1:mycontrol ID="control" runat="server" mycustomprop="val"/>`; I'm not sure if you do have the same!!

Comment: The value is read from the database. There is no way to predetermine the color at code-writing time.

Comment: How about `Constructor` of your `Control Class`?  I have added some real customization to the control over there!!

Comment: That's an interesting idea. I am currently putting the control into the markup, but this is definitely a choice. I will experiment along these lines.

Answer (score -1):

Try the Page_Load, this would work with your requirements.

Comment: I doubt that, since Page_Load will be executed even later than Page_Init and Page_Init is too late as well.

Comment: Try setting the color into the load, there all properties would have been loaded correctly.

Comment: MoustafaS, because you asked me I have tried it, but it did not yield the result you expected. The cause of this is that Page_Init is executing the assignment too late and Page_Load is executed even later.

Comment: Sorry for the many tries, what I meant is that leave only the color initianlization to be on load of the page, or Add a function that just initializes the color, and then call it after loading from the page, something like 
colorPicker.SetColor("#123456")
And add this into the control itself, this function would check 
foreach(var c in this.Controls)
if(c is HtmlInputHidden)
c.value = "color";

Comment: Thank you for trying to help, but unfortunately this was already tried.